# How to keep an activity running to check network?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions

How to always keep an activity running on the device?

I'm trying to create a chat app like Whatsapp and I want to keep an activity always running, even if the screen is off or the device owner in an other application to check if there is a new message in order to show a notification to the user.

Just exactly like the chat apps: Whatsapp, Viber, Facebook, Voxer, etc.

Comment: Those apps do not "keep an activity running to check network". Many will use [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). Some will use their own GCM replacement, powered by a `Service`. Some will use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` to check for new messages periodically. Getting this right from a power and bandwidth standpoint is important and difficult.

Comment: While services is a possible part of the answer.
Your delivery protocol is also important.
Are you using XMPP(jabber) like the old gTalk?
GCM? Parse push notification?

Comment: Why don't use `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: I'll try to learn it , i wasn't know what Services mean but now im watching some tuts on youtube Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's precisely what [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) are for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Handler which will keep checking for any new updates in the server, but this is not a good way since network bursts like these would be very costly.

Or you can use an IntentService, which will keep listening to any push messages from the server to your device, something like push notifications, which is probably what you are trying to achieve.